# Targeting and passing EJS constant to a post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to build a "Movie Diary" web app but am running into issues targeting the EJS element and push it as a post.

The user enters a title where it shows info about the film and space for a review. When I enter submit it brings the user typed review but not the title or poster. When I console log either of them I get undefined. So I believe I am targeting them incorrectly.

This code seems to work by getting the user entered title and pulling the necessary data to load onto a table at movie.ejs.

```
const postSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String,
  poster: Object
};

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

app.get("/input", function(req, res){
  res.render("input" , {quotePh : quotes});
});

app.post("/input", function (req, res) {


  const type = req.body.type;
  const enteredTitle = req.body.title;

        // API pull 1 for ImdbID

  var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/',
qs: {page: '1', r: 'json', type: type, s: enteredTitle},
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'API KEY'
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);


  var data = JSON.parse(body);
  var titleID = data.Search[0].imdbID;

      // API pull 2 for info
  var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/',
  qs: {i: titleID, r: 'json'},
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'API KEY'
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

  const fullData = JSON.parse(body);
  const director = fullData.Director;
  const cast = fullData.Actors;
  const poster = fullData.Poster;
  const title = fullData.Title;
  const year = fullData.Year;
  const writer = fullData.Writer;
  const genre = fullData.Genre;
  const imdbScore = fullData.Ratings[0].Value;
  const rtScore = fullData.Ratings[1].Value;
  const mcScore = fullData.Ratings[2].Value;
  const boxOffice = fullData.BoxOffice;



res.render("movie" , {
  movieDirector : director,
  movieCast : cast ,
  moviePoster : poster ,
  movieTitle : title ,
  movieYear : year ,
  movieWriter : writer ,
  movieGenre : genre ,
  movieImdbScore : imdbScore ,
  movieRtScore : rtScore ,
  movieMcScore : mcScore ,
  movieBoxOffice : boxOffice
});
});
});
});
```

All of the above code works as expected. The issue is when I try and pass the post to the home screen it only brings the user review and not the title of the movie or its poster.

```
app.post("/movie", function(req, res){

  const post = new Post({
    poster: req.body.posterImage,
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  });

  post.save(function(err){
    if (!err){
        res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});
});
```

How do I properly target the title and the poster? Is it not req.body or are they not string/object in the schema or something else?

movie.ejs

```
<div class="grid-container">

  <div class="poster">

    <img src="<%= moviePoster %>" name="posterImage" alt="poster-img">

  </div>
  <div class="title" name="postTitle" value="<%= movieTitle %>">

    <h2> <%= movieTitle %> </h2>

  </div>
  <div class="year">

    <h3> <%= movieYear %> </h3>

  </div>
  <div class="crew">

    <table class="table table-striped">

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>
            <h4> Director: </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieDirector %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>
            <h4> Writer: </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieWriter %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>
            <h4> Cast: </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieCast %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>
            <h4> Genre: </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieGenre %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>
            <h4> Box Office: </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieBoxOffice %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div class="critic">

    <table class="table table-striped">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Source</th>
          <th scope="col"> </th>
          <th scope="col">Score</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><img src="/images/small.png" alt="imdb" class="icon" ></th>
          <td>
            <h4> </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieImdbScore %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><img src="/images/rt.png" alt="rt" class="icon" ></th>
          <td>
            <h4> </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieRtScore %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><img src="/images/mc.png" alt="mc" class="icon" ></th>
          <td>
            <h4> </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieMcScore %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

  <form class="" action="/movie" method="post">
    <div class="review">
      <h3>Review</h3>

      <textarea name="postBody" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>


    </div>
    <div class="enter">

      <h3>Your Score</h3>

      <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" name="userScore" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
        <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
      </div>

      <script>
        var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function() {
          output.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
      </script>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

home.ejs

```
  <%  posts.forEach(function(post){ %>

    <h1><%=post.title%></h1>
    <p>
      <img src="<%= post.poster %>">
    <%=post.content%>
    </p>

    <% }) %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

posterImage and postTitle is outside of the form in your html so these values won't included in the request body. Maybe you can check the form data when you are clicking on submit using Chrome Developer Tool's Network tab.

Please move the form tag to contain all the params.

new movie.ejs will look like this.

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <form class="" action="/movie" method="post">

  <div class="poster">

    <img src="<%= moviePoster %>" name="posterImage" alt="poster-img">

  </div>
  <div class="title" name="postTitle" value="<%= movieTitle %>">

    <h2> <%= movieTitle %> </h2>

  </div>
  <div class="year">

    <h3> <%= movieYear %> </h3>

  </div>
  <div class="crew">

    <table class="table table-striped">

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>
            <h4> Director: </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieDirector %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>
            <h4> Writer: </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieWriter %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>
            <h4> Cast: </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieCast %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>
            <h4> Genre: </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieGenre %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>
            <h4> Box Office: </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieBoxOffice %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div class="critic">

    <table class="table table-striped">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Source</th>
          <th scope="col"> </th>
          <th scope="col">Score</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><img src="/images/small.png" alt="imdb" class="icon" ></th>
          <td>
            <h4> </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieImdbScore %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><img src="/images/rt.png" alt="rt" class="icon" ></th>
          <td>
            <h4> </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieRtScore %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><img src="/images/mc.png" alt="mc" class="icon" ></th>
          <td>
            <h4> </h4>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h5> <%= movieMcScore %> </h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

    <div class="review">
      <h3>Review</h3>

      <textarea name="postBody" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>


    </div>
    <div class="enter">

      <h3>Your Score</h3>

      <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" name="userScore" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
        <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
      </div>

      <script>
        var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function() {
          output.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
      </script>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Bluespider. I moved the form to contain all params but when I use   
  var postTitle = req.body.postTitle;

console.log(postTitle);             It continues to return undefined.   Do I need to call it a different way?